# Jira JQL to find issues which linked with Test Case through Adaptavist (Zephyr Scale) plugin

Tags: jira, jql

I have Jira issuetype requirement and test cases which connected with requirement by Adaptavist (Zephyr Scale) plugin.
I see in the Requirement issue the block "Tracebility" and list of testcases.

Please help:

1. How to write JQL to find requirement If I know Test Case key?;
2. How to find Requirement using JQL which [do not] have test cases?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRvtZ.jpg)

Comment: Did you found any answer to this?